# jsp:useBean with Simple Singleton

Tags: java, jsp, singleton

I have a class that I'm trying to retrieve a variable value from on my jsp page but because it's a Singleton, it seems to be having issues.

**MyController.java**

```
public class MyController {

    private static volatile MyController myController = new MyController();
    private Integer id;

    private MyController() {
    }

    public static MyController MyController() {
        return myController;
    }

    public void display() {
        id = 1;
    }

}
```

**test.jsp**:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="myController" scope="application" class="test.controller.MyController"/>
        <p>
            The ID is: ${myController.id}!
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error**:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.test_jsp

Also, I'm not sure how to call the `display()` method from the jsp page to initialize the `id` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not se jsp:useBean anymore. BTW, jsp:seBan expects a public no-arg constructor to instantiate the bean, and you don't want a new instance, since the bean is supposed to be a singleton.

Simply use a servlet that is initialized at deployment time or a context listener to store the singleton in the application scope, and use it directly, using EL, from your JSP:

```
servletContext.setAttribute("myController", MyController.getInstance());
```

Comment: How is this an acceptable answer?  Where should the line be inserted? What class/package is servletContext?